# A shorthand for rIght-click...paste

Tags: emacs, paste

It doesn't always work to ctrl+y to paste text (while it works in emacs and at the terminal). Is there something that always work so I don't have to right-click and select paste in the terminal when copying from another program? I think that there was a program used for instance when copying to contents of a file to the clipboard and then pasting it.

Comment: What are you trying to paste text into?

Comment: Have you tried control+shift+v?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press the middle mouse button to directly paste into the terminal at the cursor position.

Comment: You should add that this does not paste what was copied with Ctrl + c, but the last selection made with the mouse.